# How to update machine type property through GCP deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I have a python template as shown below for a compute instance type along with other needed config.yaml file.

`...
CONTROLLER_MACHINE_TYPE='n1-standard-8'
controller_template = {
    'name': 'controller-it',
    'type': 'it_template.py',
    'properties': {
        'machineType': CONTROLLER_MACHINE_TYPE,
        'dockerImage': CONTROLLER_IMAGE,
        'dockerEnv': {
            'ADC_LISTEN_QUEUE': 'controller-subscriber'
        },
        'zone': ZONE,
        'network': NETWORK_NAME,
        'saEmail': SA_EMAIL
    }
}`

**it_template.py contents**

```
def GenerateConfig(context):
    resources = [{
        'name': context.env['name'],
        'type': 'compute.v1.instanceTemplate',
        'properties': {
            'zone': context.properties['zone'],
            'properties': {
                "machineType": context.properties['machineType'],
                "metadata": {
                    "items": [{
                        "key": 'gce-container-declaration',
                        "value": GenerateManifest(context)
                    }]
                }, ...
```

I have deployed it with the environment named qa. Now after sometime I realized that I need to change the machine type of this instance. For eg instead of n1-standard-8, I want my qa environment to update the type of machine for this resource.

However I don't see any example which mentions about updating the property of any resource.

Can we update the property of a resource in an environment using gcp deployment manager?
Or I need to add a new resource with another name and desired machine type property?

**Update**

As suggested by @jordi Miralles, I modified my template to have machineType as n1-standard-16 and tried to update the deployment.

But I got below error

`cloud deployment-manager deployments update qa --config dm_config.yaml
The fingerprint of the deployment is KkD38j9KYiBTiaIW8SltbA==
Waiting for update [operation-1525444590548-56b623ef1b421-b4733efd-53174d1b]...failed.

ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1525444590548-56b623ef1b421-b4733efd-53174d1b]: errors:
- code: NO_METHOD_TO_UPDATE_FIELD
  message: No method found to update field 'properties' on resource 'controller-it'
    of type 'compute.v1.instanceTemplate'. The resource may need to be recreated with
    the new field.`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update resources in your deployment manager, there is no need to create a new one with a different name if you want to change a resource. See [updating a deployment](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments#make_the_update_request)

You can use your existing deployment yaml file with the changes you want to apply and then update your existing deployment:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments update [EXISTING DEPLOYMENT] --config [UPDATED YAML]
```

Take into account that your instance must be **stopped**. All other implications on [changing machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type) apply. Also, no data on any of your persistent disks will be lost.

Remember to turn on the instances when the update finishes!

Comment: Thanks for your response. As suggested I updated the deployment but got the error. I have update it in main contents above.

Comment: Take a look at this answer from serverfault, it may be useful for you: https://serverfault.com/questions/726490/getting-a-mysterious-missing-field-error-creating-a-compute-v1-instancetemplate